# Crash due to mixing CRTP & interfaces?

Tags: c++, interface, crash, crtp

I am experimenting with CRTP and mixing it with interfaces, and I cannot explain why this program crashes (in Clang, GCC and MSVC). In latest Clang and GCC it builds without warning with -Wall, -Wextra. My guess is that the virtual method call is not resolved but I cannot explain why (no crash if GetInt() is removed from the interface). In my debugger I see that the crash happens on line `static_cast<T*>(this)->GetInt()`.

```
#include <iostream>

class INode
{
public:
    virtual int GetInt() = 0;
protected:
    ~INode() {}
};

template<template<class> typename NodeBase>
class Node : public INode, public NodeBase<Node<NodeBase>>
{
public:
    int GetInt() override { return 42; }
};

template<typename T>
class MyNodeBase
{
public:
    int CallGetInt() {
        return static_cast<T*>(this)->GetInt();
    }
};

template<template<class> typename NodeBase>
int Foo1(Node<NodeBase> n) {
    return n.CallGetInt();
}

template<typename T>
int Foo2(MyNodeBase<T> n) {
    return n.CallGetInt();
}

int main() {
    Node<MyNodeBase> n;
    std::cout << Foo1(n) << std::endl; // ok
    std::cout << Foo2(n) << std::endl; // crash
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) `n` in your call to `Foo2`.

`Foo2` accepts its parameter by value.  That means that a *copy* of `n`'s `MyNodeBase<Node<MyNodeBase>>` sub-object is what gets passed to `Foo2`.  Since `n` in `Foo2` is not a `Node<MyNodeBase>`, calling `GetInt` through the pointer returned from the cast in `CallGetInt` results in your program exhibiting undefined behavior.

If you change `Foo2` to accept its parameter by reference, you program's behavior would be well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

`Foo2` argument is passed by value. So the complete object `n` is of type `MyNodeBase<Node<MyNodeBase>>`. It is not a derived of `Node<MyNodeBase>`. But the expression `static_cast<T*>(this)` assumes that `this` is derived of `Node<MyNodeBase>` thus `static_cast<T*>(this)->GetInt()` is undefined behavior.

You avoid this error:

```
template<typename T>
class MyNodeBase
{
protected:
   MyNodeBase() = default;
   MyNodeBase(const MyNodeBase&) = default;
   MyNodeBase& operator = (const MyNodeBase&) = default;

public:
    
    int CallGetInt() {
        return static_cast<T*>(this)->GetInt();
    }
};
```